# mysql joins using group by

Tags: mysql, join, having

These are my tables

```
mysql> select * from professor;
    +-------+--------+--------+--------+------+
    | empid | name   | status | salary | age  |
    +-------+--------+--------+--------+------+
    |     1 | Arun   |      1 |   2000 |   23 |
    |     2 | Benoy  |      0 |   3000 |   25 |
    |     3 | Chacko |      1 |   1000 |   36 |
    |     4 | Divin  |      0 |   5000 |   32 |
    |     5 | Edwin  |      1 |   2500 |   55 |
    +-------+--------+--------+--------+------+
    5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from works;
+----------+-------+---------+
| courseid | empid | classid |
+----------+-------+---------+
|        1 |     1 |      10 |
|        2 |     2 |       9 |
|        3 |     3 |       8 |
|        4 |     4 |      10 |
|        5 |     5 |       9 |
|        6 |     1 |       9 |
|        2 |     3 |      10 |
|        2 |     1 |       7 |
|        4 |     2 |       6 |
|        7 |     5 |       6 |
|        3 |     5 |       2 |
|        2 |     4 |       6 |
|        2 |     5 |       2 |
+----------+-------+---------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from course;
+----------+------------+--------+
| courseid | coursename | points |
+----------+------------+--------+
|        1 | Maths      |      4 |
|        2 | Science    |      4 |
|        3 | English    |     85 |
|        4 | Social     |      4 |
|        5 | Malayalam  |     99 |
|        6 | Arts       |     40 |
|        7 | Biology    |    100 |
+----------+------------+--------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Question is :

```
Return the names of full professors who have taught at least two courses in one Class
```

My query is :

```
select professor.name from professor
inner join works
on professor.empid=works.empid
group by works.empid
having count(distinct works.courseid)>=2
```

The ouput I get now is :

```
Arun
Benoy
Chacko
Divin
Edwin
```

I am supposed to get the ouput as 'Edwin' as he is the only person who has taught 2 subjects in the same class. Pls help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must consider your group by is wrong change it to this

```
   group by classid,works.empid
```

like that you will count courseid in classid .

Comment: Thank you. That worked :)  I really bad at doing queries with group by. Could you pls tell mw what group by really does?

Comment: you welcome dude :) :group by is to group the result set by one or more columns . in your case you group by the classid and then group by empid.

Comment: I never understood the idea of using 2 columns with group by. Guess I will learn more when I practice more :)